# How to set up jsx syntax highlight and Intellisense in Visual Studio Code 1.5.2?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I'm new to Reactjs and I'm trying to configure VSCode for react and jsx.

The available information seems outdated...
I managed to configure reactjs in VScode.

I installed the following extensions:

- Typings Installer
- Typings
- Babel ES6/ES7
- Reactjs Code Snippets
- jsx by TwentyChung

VSCode Language mode now shows "Javascript React".

What I can't get to work is react-jsx syntax highlight and intellisense.
What am I missing? Are there any instructions about jsx configuration?

Windows 10 64, VSCode 1.5.2, react files in .js

Thanks,

Enrico

Comment: You can check out my boilerplate. It has some of the features you are looking for: https://github.com/skolmer/react-hot-boilerplate-vscode

Comment: Hi @Steffen, thanks for your help. I followed your instructions, the ESlint server is running and the whole boilerplate has been installed, but I still don't have any jsx highlighting... On the bottom bar now I have Javascript React, Typescript 2.0.3, ESLint

Comment: If it shows Javascript React than everything is working as expected. The JSX syntax highlighting is currently not perfect. Sometimes the highlighting can break based on your code style (linebreaks e.g.). Template literals in attributes are not correctly highlighted and other details are missing. But the vscode folks are pushing new updates every month so I'm confident this will get better over the next month. Pleas check the vscode github repo for known bugs. You should also check out the different color schemes in vscode. some are better for JSX than others.

Comment: And you should try if you get better results when you uninstall `jsx by TwentyChung`. This extension was created when JSX syntax support was still missing in vscode.

Comment: @Steffen, thanks again. jsx uninstalled. Still no syntax highlight but everything else seems to work. Is it possible to have auto completion for jsx? It would be great to have closing tags...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS Code supports JSX syntax highlighting and IntelliSense out of the box. It also supports features like auto-closing tags and auto imports for JSX

You do not need to install extensions. Many of the ones referenced in the question will actually cause problems and are not actively being maintained

Answer (score 2):

I'm not contradicting the previous answer, but it's also worth noting that [this issue](https://github.com/textmate/html.tmbundle/issues/119) is currently open because VS Code is not highlighting syntax or formatting code for `text/jsx` blocks inside HTML files. At the time of writing, there is a PR open (linked from the issue) which will hopefully fix the issue but it has not yet been merged.